# Need help in drawGradientArea

Tags: php, pchart

I am new to pchart, I already downloaded the latest version of pChart and test an example and it worked fine for me, and then I tried to test this: [drawGradientArea](http://wiki.pchart.net/doc.draw.gradientarea.html).

When I copied and pasted the code in my php file, it did not show the output or the image.

How do I show the image like the link that I provided?